# ios pointer problems

Tags: iphone, ios, pointers

hi guys having some problems with pointers this is my code

```
NSArray *buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: self.btn1, self.btn2, self.btn3,nil];

 for(UIButton *btn in buttons){

    NSLog(@"%f, %f, %@", btn.bounds.size.width, btn.frame.size.height,  btn.titleLabel.text);
 }
```

The out put is `"0.00000, 0.00000, button1"`
any ideas whats going wrong???

Comment: have you tried btn.frame.size like

Comment: where you set frame for buttons ?

Comment: where do you call this? Do you create buttons in code, maybe you do really have them zeroes (i.e. size.width really equals to 0)?

Comment: seems like self.btn2 is nil, if this is the only line you got

Comment: @MANIAK_dobrii that's impossible - NSArrays can't contain `nil` objects.

Comment: @ReneJennrich again, ***NSArray cannot contain nil objects!***

Comment: @H2CO3 i mean frames contain zeroes

Comment: it's look like you have not created these added button  before adding them to NSArray

it happening due to the below reason.

1) you were creating these button through the XIB and adding them into NSArray inside the `videDidLoad ` method  if so you should try your code inside the viewWillAppear

Comment: @H2CO3 you're right but that was not the point, NSArray will stop its init process when you pass `nil`. So I assumed the second object was `nil`, and because of that the array contains only self.btn1. But I guess I didn't get the right problem, because the threadstarter seems to consider more about the framesize than the missing two lines (seems like he shortened it). Finally I think we won't get a solution without the code where the buttons are created.

Comment: sorry for the late reply; the buttons are set in the storyboard and they are linked as well.  Putting the code in the Viewdidappear delegate works although the program is a bit sloppy because of it. hope tour all still there.

Answer (score 0):

Retry with this code just set frame in `viewDidLoad:` method ,like bellow..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    ///set frame which you want..

    self.btn1 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 44)];
    self.btn2 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 70, 100, 44)];
    self.btn3 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 120, 100, 44)];
}
```

Comment: frames are already set, the buttons have been linked in the view controller.